# python kill threads waiting queued tasks

Tags: python, multithreading

I have stoppable reusable thread.

```
class _Thread(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self, function, queue):
    super(_Thread, self).__init__()
    self._stop = threading.Event()
    self._function = function
    self._queue = queue
    self.daemon = True

  def run(self):
    while not self._stop.isSet():
      item = self._queue.get()
      item.result = self._function(item.args)
      self._queue.task_done()
      item.setReady()

  def stop(self):
    self._stop.set()

  def isStopped(self):
    return self._stop.isSet()
```

I need to kill thread all of the tasks are processed. How to do that? Stop signal here really does not work because thread is stuck at _queue.get(). I don't want to use timeouts on get() or make it unblocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a "stop" variable, insert a special item into the queue (say, a `None`) which tells the thread to exit.

```
  def run(self):
    while True:
      item = self._queue.get()
      if item is None:
        return
      item.result = self._function(item.args)
      self._queue.task_done()
      item.setReady()
```

Comment: Thx, that is exactly what I did after posting the question.))